# Three Column PHP Results Table

Tags: php, loops, html-table

I'm trying to display my mysql query into a fairly unique table.
The characteristics are as follows:

1. The results table has 3 columns
2. The top right cell is reserved for other content

[result1][result2][content]

[result3][result4][result5]

[result6][result7][result8]

...etc

The query can bring back as few as 1 result.
But I'm struggling to get what i need included in the loop.

If anyone knows how to go after something like this, I'd love some help!
Thanks in advance!

EDIT ** HERE IS MY CODE SO FAR

the results are coming through in three columns, but I can't get the condition to display other static content in the top right cell.

```
$row = 0;
$column = 0;
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($column == 0) {echo "<tr>";}
    if (($column == 2) && ($row == 0)){echo "<td>content</td></tr><tr>";}
  echo "<td>".$row['business']."</td>";
  $column++;
  if ($column >= 3) {
    $row++;
    echo "</tr>";
    $column = 0;
  }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Show the code you've written so far

Comment: What have you tried? I would go with a simple loop through your MySQL result array and conditions like "i == 3" for the "content" section and "i%3 == 0" to start a new row.

Comment: Is this just a regular html table, or some pure css version?

Comment: @MarcB - yes, regular html table

Comment: My original code was much like Marc's so I'm working off of that example now.

Comment: @Paul - I have added my code so far to the OP

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a pure html table, you'd have

```
$row = 0;
$column = 0;
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   if ($column == 0) {
      echo '<tr>';
   }
   if (($column == 2) && ($row = 0))
      echo '<td>content</td></tr><tr>'; // output special content, start new row
   }
   echo "<td>$row[something]</td>";
   $column++;
   if ($column >= 3) {
      $row++;
      echo '</tr>';
      $column = 0;
   }
}
echo '</table>';
```

probably won't work as-is, but should give you the general idea. Basically just output rows/columns until you reach the 1st row/3rd column then output your special content, otherwise just out

Comment: Thanks Marc. I'm getting results over three columns, but the third column in EVERY row is returning a false $row[something], instead of the "content" on row one and valid $row[something] in rows 2+. Any ideas? Oh and I added an extra curly bracket before "echo" on your second IF statement.

Comment: The code i added to my original post loads everything in three columns, but it looks like the conditional statement for the top right cell isn't working. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your results rows in `$rows`, split it into an array of arrays:

```
$table = array();
while (count($rows)){
   $group = array_slice($rows, 0, 3);
   $rows = array_slice($rows, 3);
   while (count($group) < 3) $group[] = array();
   $table[] = $group;
}
```

Now `$table` contains an array of 3-element arrays. The final one is padded to have 3 elements in it, adding empty arrays until we have 3. Then just output it:

```
foreach ($table as $group){
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($group as $row){
        if ($row['id']){
            echo "<td>".format_data($row)."</td>\n";
        }else{
            # empty padding cell on last row
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```